# How to remove an object of an array if its ID is the same of an other arrays object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to remove an object of an array if its ID is the same as of an object in an other array. But I don't know how to do it.

Example:

```
parentArray1 = [ 
  { 
     id: 101
     ... 
  }, { 
     REMOVE THIS OBJECT BECAUSE ITS ID IS THE SAME AS parentArray2[0].id
     id: 102 
     ...
  }, { 
     id: 103 
     ...
  } 
];

parentArray2 = [ 
  { 
     id: 102 // SAME ID AS parentArray1[1].id
     ... 
  }  
];
```

Does anyone have an idea or an solution?

Comment: Can you format your example arrays? Right now there are not arrays and it's is hard to right code out of this.

Comment: what is type of parentArray1 and parentArray2? Object or array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter, to keep an element if it does not match **some** element in the second:

```
parentArray1.filter(elt1 => !parentArray2.some(elt2 => elt2.id === elt1.id))
```

Here it is in line-by-line commented format:

```
parentArray1                       // From parentArray1
  .filter(                         // keep all the
    elt1 =>                        // elements for which 
      !                            // it is not the case that
      parentArray2                 // parentArray2
        .some(                     // has some
          elt2 =>                  // elements for which
            elt2.id                // the id
            ===                    // is equal to
            elt1.id))              // the id of the first element.
```

A bit of ES6 destructuring for you:

```
parentArray1.filter(({id1}) => !parentArray2.some(({id2}) => id1 === id2))
```

In ES5, without arrow functions:

```
parentArray.filter(function(elt1) {
  return !parentArray2.some(function(elt2) {
    return elt2.id === elt1.id;
  });
})
```

If you want to do this with for-loops:

```
result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < parentArray1.length; i++) {
  var include = true;
  for (var j = 0; j < parentArray2.length; j++) {
    if (parentArray1[i].id === parentArray2[j].id) include = false;
  }
  if (include) result.push(parentArray1[i]);
}
```

You might also want to consider pre-calculating a list of ids to be removed:

```
var removeIds = parentArray2.map(elt => elt.id);
```

Now you can filter `parentArray1` more easily:

```
parentArray1.filter(elt => !removeIds.contains(elt.id))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) now im using your for-loops solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` and `find()` to get desired result.

```js
var parentArray1 = [{
  id: 101
}, {
  id: 102
}, {
  id: 103
}];

var parentArray2 = [{
  id: 102
}, {
  id: 199
}];

var result = parentArray1.filter(function(o) {
  return !parentArray2.find(function(e) {
    return o.id == e.id
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, i prepare some example codes(copy to 3th array, remove from array, `function` and `prototype`).
Try with:

**Copy to a new array:**

```js
var a = [
    {id:1,name:"Paul"},
    {id:2,name:"Andre"},
    {id:3,name:"Sophie"},
    {id:4,name:"Anton"},
    {id:5,name:"John"},
    {id:6,name:"Einar"}
];
var b = [
    {id:2,name:"Andre"},
    {id:5,name:"John"}
];

var c = [];

a.forEach(function(aItem, aIndex) {
    var copy = true;    
    b.forEach(function(bItem, bIndex) {
        if (aItem.id === bItem.id) {
            copy = false;
        }
    });
    
    if(copy === true) {
        c.push(aItem);
    }
    
});


console.log(c);
```

**Remove from first array:**

```js
var a = [
    {id:1,name:"Paul"},
    {id:2,name:"Andre"},
    {id:3,name:"Sophie"},
    {id:4,name:"Anton"},
    {id:5,name:"John"},
    {id:6,name:"Einar"}
];
var b = [
    {id:2,name:"Andre"},
    {id:5,name:"John"}
];

a.forEach(function(aItem, aIndex) {
    b.forEach(function(bItem, bIndex) {
        if (aItem.id === bItem.id) {
            a.splice(aIndex, 1);
        }
    });
});


console.log(a);
```

**As function:**

```js
var a = [
    {id:1,name:"Paul"},
    {id:2,name:"Andre"},
    {id:3,name:"Sophie"},
    {id:4,name:"Anton"},
    {id:5,name:"John"},
    {id:6,name:"Einar"}
];
var b = [
    {id:2,name:"Andre"},
    {id:5,name:"John"}
];

function removeItemFromArrayByIndexObject(from, to, index) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
        var append = true;
        for (var j = 0; j < to.length; j++) if (from[i][index] === to[j][index]) append = false;
        if (append === true) result.push(from[i]);
    }
    return result;
}


console.log(removeItemFromArrayByIndexObject(a, b, 'id'))
```

**As prototype:**

```js
// first array
var a = [
    {id:1,name:"Paul"},
    {id:2,name:"Andre"},
    {id:3,name:"Sophie"},
    {id:4,name:"Anton"},
    {id:5,name:"John"},
    {id:6,name:"Einar"}
];
// second array
var b = [
    {id:2,name:"Andre"},
    {id:5,name:"John"}
];
// create prototype
Array.prototype.removeItemFromArrayByIndexObject = function (to, index) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        var remove = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < to.length; j++) if (this[i][index] === to[j][index]) remove = true;
        if (remove === true) this.splice(i, 1);
    }
    return this;
}
// apply
a.removeItemFromArrayByIndexObject(b, 'id')
// log
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findIndex` and if you get valid index, splice it.

```js
parentArray1 = [{
  id: 101
}, {
  //REMOVE THIS OBJECT BECAUSE ITS ID IS THE SAME AS parentArray2[0].id
  id: 102
}, {
  id: 103
}, {
  //REMOVE THIS OBJECT BECAUSE ITS ID IS THE SAME AS parentArray2[0].id
  id: 102
}];

parentArray2 = [{
  id: 102 // SAME ID AS parentArray1[1].id
}];

for(var i = 0; i< parentArray2.length; i++){
  var index = parentArray1.findIndex(x=>x.id === parentArray2[i].id);
  if(index !== -1){
    parentArray1.splice(index,1);
    i--;
  }
}

console.log(parentArray1)
```